# Populating a jsp dropdown with database values in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my jsp page the following works flawlessly to populate an html dropdown:

```
<td><select name="idbilltype" id="required">
<c:forEach items="${result13.rows}" var="row13">
<option value="${row13.idtcode}">${row13.nmdescription}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select></td>
```

I also have a button on my jsp page that successfully launches some javascript to add a row to my table:

```
<button type="button" style="font-size : 10px;" onclick="instblrws()">Add Row</button>
```

Lastly my javascript adds a row/cell successfully - but does not populate the dropdown:

```
function instblrws() {
var table = document.getElementById("dyntbl");
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = "<select name='idbilltype' id='required'>"
+ "<c:forEach items='${result13.rows}' var='row13'>"
+ "<option value='${row13.idtcode}'>${row13.nmdescription}</option>"
+ "</c:forEach></select>";
```

I understand I am improperly trying to merge my jsp code into my js function but I am struggling to figure out how to separate the two properly getting this to work as desired.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if `<c:forEach` would work if you use it as string within `innerHTML` what if you are do the loop via JS to concate the option?

Comment: your dropdown remain same  throughout your code..whenever you add new row ,if yes use `.clone` to clone the select box and use anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think the iterate and concatenate on the dataset contained in result13.rows is probably the best way to go for what I am trying to do but I am having trouble parsing this in javascript.  Is there an easy way to do this?